# Template not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, partial-views

I have a problem that occurs sometimes, when the template entry is not defined in the template cache, it happens every once in a while after reloading the page.

The related code:

index.html

```
<div ng-include src="'Views/templates.html'"></div>
```

Views/templates.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate/spare-request-item.html">    
  <div>..</div>
</script>
```

directive.js

```
.directive("spare", function ($templateCache) {
console.log($templateCache.info());, //return length 30 when it fails, 31 otherwise
console.log($templateCache.get('customTemplate/spare-request-item.html'));//return undefined when it fails
return {
    ..
    templateUrl: 'customTemplate/spare-request-item.html',
```

Anyone else has experienced this or know how to assure that the template is loaded and parsed before the directive runs? It is a angular bug?

Comment: what is the question? Where is the problem? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand... you have an html file and within that the entire HTML is wrapped in an `ng-template` script ? To what end ?

Comment: @OmriAharon Basically I pretend to use a single file (templates.html), in the middle of that I got this error, I put the template in a single file to be sure that is has nothing to do with multiple templates in a single file.

Comment: Why not just have `templateUrl: 'templates.html'` in the directive then and remove the script wrapper ?

Comment: That should work, I think, but like I said, I pretend to put several templates in one file, to avoid too many http requests and having multiple tiny templates files, anyway I also have a similar code to replace an inline defined template the same way and that template works always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular compiles the directives as it goes over DOM. You can't have it "wait" on a directive. What you *could* do, is not to show the directive until templates have loaded.

I don't think this is a good approach since it requires "knowledge" on the part of the user of the directive:

```
<div ng-include="'Views/templates.html'" 
     onload="$root.templatesLoaded = true"></div>

<my-directive ng-if="templatesLoaded"></my-directive>
```

Another approach would be to manually load all the templates and the directive's specific template. Here's a conceptual way of how to do this:

```
app.directive("foo", function($templateRequest, $templateCache, $compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $templateRequest("templates.html")
        .then(function(templateContainer) {
          $compile(templateContainer);
          return undefined; // just to show that no need to return anything
        })
        .then(function() {
          var template = $templateCache.get("foo.html");
          if (template) {
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }
        });
    }
  }
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nccebDlETEifK9qmFMso?p=preview)

`$templateRequest` is used here since it caches the `templates.html` template (to prevent double-requests), but it is a "lazy" use, since you would not actually need the template with `id === "templates.html"`.

You can abstract it into a service, of course, to make it nicer.

Typically, however, I have seen directive developers embed the template in the .js file of the directive. This frees the user of the directive from loading separate `.html` files to make the directives work. I suppose you could load themes this way.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but for some reason, that renders different when the template get loaded that way, I suppose I'm gonna put the template in the js, it was not my intention because viewing/editing a multiline string in javascript is not the nicest thing in the world.

Comment: @MatiasMolina, not sure why it renders differently - it shouldn't. If you can replicate in jsfiddle/plunker, I can take a look. Yes, editing template as a string is a pain, but that's why there are dev-time concerns and run-time concerns. There are tools (I'm not sure exactly what) that help merge templates into their respective .js during deployment

Comment: @MatiasMolina, did you resolve your issue? If the answer helped, consider accepting

Comment: I finally put into the template cache the template as a multiline javascript string in a module, that the directive module referenced like a dependency. Even if I didn't find out why it failed randomly to load/parse the template, I guess you pushed me in the final direction.